# Select ONLY true values from conditional statement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

A really quick one hopefully

I have the statement below. How would I make it only return TRUE values and drop the FALSE values from the resulting dataframe?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: `dfx=df [df.groupby('tac')['latitude'].nunique()>2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new `Series` with same size like `df` filled by number of unique values for possible filter original rows:

```
dfx = df[df.groupby('tac')['latitude'].transform('nunique') > 2]
```